# How to stream /dev/video0 with VLC remotely?

Tags: linux, video, vlc-media-player, streaming, http

I am trying to stream composite a/v to HTTP.
The following command works for me but the problem with it is that I need to press PLAY once VLC GUI pops up. This command only works on host PC and not remotely via SSH or VLM

> ./vlc -vvv /dev/video0 --sout
>   '#transcode{venc=x264{preset=ultrafast},vcodec=h264,vb=800,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.55:9001}'

Is there a way to run this from remote PC and autostart without me having to press the PLAY button?

Comment: There's better ways of streaming /dev/video0 than using VLC. What are you trying to achieve ? Just stream the video device to the LAN ?

Comment: It will be sent over WAN so I was hoping for either HTTP or RTSP. I tried ffserver/ffmpeg without much luck

Comment: With Audio ? Without Audio ? I've used ffmpeg over the internet before but that was video only.

Comment: Both, audio and video. ffmpeg returned an error saying card is not capable of doing what I asked it to do. No information on google was available on that error msg so I just gave up.

Comment: What sort of device is /dev/video0 ?

Comment: hauppauge wintv-pvr-150 MCE

Comment: I may have one of these at home. Maybe I'll try it out tonight and see how I go. Otherwise I'm out of ideas, sorry.